# Winhost Error after fresh install of BlogEngine.Net

Tags: web-hosting, blogengine.net

After installing BlogEngine.net through the WinHost control panel I'm getting the following error

> Ooops! An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> This one's down to me! Please accept my apologies for this - I'll see
>   to it that the developer responsible for this happening is given 20
>   lashes (but only after he or she has fixed this problem).

I am able to add new blog entries on the main site, so I do have write access to App_Data... I only receive the error when going to "users" or "settings", etc.

Can anyone help on this one?

Comment: Have you install it correctly? You can ask their support team to install it for you. :)

Comment: If I knowingly installed it incorrectly would I waste my time posting on SO? Although I do appreciate all of the support received through this site maybe keeping comments constructive would benefit others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received response from BlogEngine.Net on CodePlex. Answer is at https://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/523930

Their response was to change web.config

```
> In web.config, change from: <!--<trust level="Medium"/>--> to:  <trust level="Full"/>
```

Hope this helps someone else who installed through WinHost.